# Connect Tarantool Docker image to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, tarantool

I'm trying to connect Tarantool Docker Image to local PostgreSQL, to replicate some test data, and ran into the following problems:

1. It seems there is no CL (except Tarantool console) to check which
   files are in place (exec bin/bash fails)
2. pg = require('pg') leads to
   an error: "init.lua:4: module 'pg.driver' not found", despite the
   presence of the pg module in the Docker description
3. I have doubts about how to replicate efficiently 4 tables, and
   relations between them, to the container from outside Postgres

Does anyone know sources to dig in and find solutions to those problems? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. `docker exec -ti tnt_container sh`
2. [the issue](https://github.com/tarantool/docker/issues/189). You should find an older base image or build it yourself.
3. This is PostgreSQL-related doubts. You may pass batches of data to pg functions or use intermediate application to transfer data via COPY. It looks like [tarantool's pg driver](https://github.com/tarantool/pg) does not support COPY.

Comment: Many thanks. 1) resolved 2) Which Postgres version do you recommend to install? (I assume 8.1 as in here: https://github.com/tarantool/pg is a bit obsolete 3) I will try

Comment: 8.1+ is about backward compatibility. I don't have any problems with the driver.

Comment: luarocks install pg
Warning: Failed searching manifest: Failed fetching manifest for http://rocks.tarantool.org/ 
...
Error: No results matching query were found.

As well:

Comment: As well:
apk add tarantool-dev
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  tarantool-dev (missing):
    required by: world[tarantool-dev]

Do you suggest I build a Docker image from scratch on, for example, Debian, with all required dependencies?